# How to install JuiceUI for a VS solution (ASP.NET)?

Tags: asp.net

the problem is i cant install [JuiceUI](http://juiceui.com/) for a VS Solution.

My actions:

1) Create a new WebApplication with Visual Studio 2010.
2) Install JuiceUI thru Nudget.
3) After that I find the following string in the Web.config:

```
    <pages>
      <controls>
...
        <add assembly="JuiceUI" namespace="Juice" tagPrefix="juice" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
```

4) But "juice" doesn't work. I guess it's because of missing juice.dll in the bin folder or something like that.

But where can I find this dll and why it's not copied automatically?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure elaborating on exactly what isn't working would help someone answer the question. The path you chose to install it on a project is the correct one to take.

You might also consider using a new fork named [Brew](http://shellscape.org/#brew)